# Pseudo Homophones - Police Officers

Tags: word, wordplay

For this riddle, I have two homophones, however the first one is a single word and the second one is composed of two or more words.

Example:
h1 - licensing
h2 - lies and sing OR lie sensing

Try to guess h1 and h2 in the following situation:
Police officer Steve and his partner Fred are taking a break from patrolling by stopping at a donut shop. Steve is waiting in the car while Fred is walking back to the car from the shop without any donuts.

> **Fred**: Steve, we have a(n) {h1}.
>   **Steve**: What is it?
>   **Fred**: {h2}!

**HINT 1**:

> The answer has more to do with their occupation than the donuts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have an

> Emergency

What is it?

> Emerge and see!

Comment: hahaha this is a great answer :D

Answer (score 6):

We have a

> stalemate

What is it?

> stale, mate! [We have an impasse: the doughnuts here are not fresh, my friend.]

But maybe I've been looking at

> chess problems

too long.

Comment: Very creative! But not the right answer. I will update with hints tomorrow if nobody gets it. +1

Answer (score 6):

We have

> an issue!

What is it?

> it's you!
>  Fred doesn't like his partner, and doesn't want to give him any donuts. :(

Comment: Not quite, but nice answer! There is a bit of a difference here between "issue" and "it's you" that is not as prevalent in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a cheapo, resorting to proper names...

> **Fred:** Steve, we have an officer down.
>  **Steve:** What is it?
>  **Fred:** Officer Doan!

Or maybe, replacing Fred with Dr. Rumack...

> **Dr. Rumack:** Steve, we have an emergency in the hospital.
>  **Steve:** What is it?
>  **Dr. Rumack:** It's a big building with patients!

Comment: Nice try, but remember h1 is a single word.

Comment: Although you are actually getting closer in your second answer.

Comment: Leslie Nielsen was a great comic actor :D but that's not important right now.